# Need Help to resolve dbt audit helper test error

Tags: dbt

I created a macro that calls another macro in dbt audit helper package .
this is the code I used :

```
    (
    {% set old_etl_relation=adapter.get_relation(
      database=target.database,
      schema="LANDING",
      identifier="STG_ORDERS"
    ) -%}

    {% set dbt_relation=ref('STG_ORDERS') %}

    {{ audit_helper.compare_relation_columns(
    a_relation=old_etl_relation,
    b_relation=dbt_relation
    ) }}
    )
```

but I am getting an error saying `jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'information_schema'`

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this issue ?